# What is the probability of random teams being selected the same way?

Tags: probability

Say you are randomly selecting 2 teams. Team A has 2 players and Team B has 3 players.

After the first selection, you get Players 1 and 2 on Team A with Players 3, 4, and 5 and Team B.

Upon hitting the magic randomize button again, what is the probability you end up with the same teams?

Is this as simple as a Binomial Coefficient where 5 choose 2 = 10 and that means there's a 10% chance? That feels overly simple to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true. Think about choosing two people for Team A only because the remaining people will be automatically in Team B. There are a total of $5\choose 2$ ways of choosing Team A members, and you favour only one of them.